# SpEL Collection Selection in IBM Conversation

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, spring-el, watson-conversation

This only relevent to IBM Watson Conversation users.

I am trying to set a context variable to the only "valid" date the user enters in the @sys-date property. A valid date here is after 01/01/1900 and before now. According to SpEL definition I should select the list with `.?[value > expression]`. Where value or #this is the current list item.

```
"context": {
    "date": "<? @sys-date and @sys-date.values ? @sys-date.values.?[value.after('1900-01-01') and value.before(now())] : null ?>",
    "thisWorks": "<? {0,1,2,3,4}.?[false] ?>",
    "thisDoesNot": "<? {0,1,2,3,4}.?[value > 1] ?>"
}
```

`thisWorks = []`
Everything else throws an error.
I have tried using `#this` but watson translates to `(intent == 'this')` and escaping like `\#this` throws an error before even trying to save.

IBM says it supports SpEL and part of the definition is collection selection. Even in [this blog post](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/06/building-chatbots-tips-tricks/) it says this type of feature is supported. However there are no examples of it and everything I have tried results in errors.

Has anyone else used collection selection in Watson Conversation and provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your question, but maybe this information can help you.

Try to save the date in one `context` variable, e.g:

```
{
  "context": {
    "date": <? @sys-date ?>;
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Are you sure about this $date?"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

And after, make your conditions...

To see if the `$date` is in the future use:

```
if bot recognizes now().before($date) or @sys-date.before($date)
response "Ok, the date is before $date."
```

If the past:

```
now().after($date) or @sys-date.after($date)
response "Ok, the date is after $date, in this case is one invalid date"
```

**Obs.:** You can use this examples inside the conditions. In your case is to use the 'valids' dates in **if bot recognizes**.

- See more [methods to process values](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/dialog-methods.html#methods-to-process-values) in Watson Conversation
- See more about the System-entity [@sys-date](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/system-entities.html#sys-datetime) in Watson Conversation

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to filter a list is to make it a list of objects. For example:

```
<? {1:1, 2:2, 3:3 }.?[value < 3 ].![value] ?>
```

Hope this helps.